# AVPlayer will not stream M4A over HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: avplayer, http-live-streaming, m4a

I am writing an iOS app and I need to stream m4a files over HTTP Live Streaming.  I am using AVPlayer and a [HLS Simple Media Playlist file](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-12#section-8.2).

If I link AVPlayer directly to an mp3 or m4a, it streams with no issues.

```
URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fembotics.com/bells.m4a"];
item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:URL];
player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
[player play];
```

The problem happens when I set `URL` to a HLS playlist.  Strangely, mp3 works and m4a does not.

http://fembotics.com/basicmp3.m3u8 - **Working**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5220
#EXTINF:20.0,
/bells.mp3
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

http://fembotics.com/basicm4a.m3u8 - **Broken**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5220
#EXTINF:20.0,
/bells.m4a
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I tried using absolute URLs in the playlists and it makes no difference.

Has anyone seen this type of issue before?  Should I try other sources for my m4a files?  (I tried one purchased from iTunes and one transcoded from wav by MediaHuman Audio Converter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m3u8 on iOS only supports segmented .aac an .ts containers.

Comment: I ran `mediafilesegmenter bells.m4a` and the resulting .m3u8 and .aac files play fine!  I wish I understood how the file was altered...

Comment: the m4a container is based on the ISO 14496-12 standard. The aac container is simply raw AAC frames with an ADTS header on every frame.